# Call event every random number

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, int

Im trying to work out how to do a event every random number. I am using the following to get a random number between 50 + 100

```
int x = (arc4random() % 50) + 50;
```

I then want to call a selector based on the returned value as so.

```
[_hero schedule:@selector(randomAnimation) interval:x];
```

Im trying to work out in my head how I would rerun the schedule after the random time is up with the `New Random time`.

Comment: Do you want a scheduler sort of things which gets called at random interval. If yes, then please visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118941/how-to-schedule-or-call-a-method-at-random-time-interval-in-cocos2d-iphone

Comment: take one array and add value from 50 to 100 in array sequence.
Create one another array which having a random value from 1 to 50.
take object value of from 1st array from 2 nd array index value.

Comment: @keyurbhalodiya - the complex, expensive way of achieving the same result as OP's slick method. The issue is not getting the random number, but rather scheduling accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the _hero class randomAnimation method :

```
-(void) randomAnimation {

    // do the animation stuff here

    // then

    int x = (arc4random() % 50) + 50;
    [self scheduleOnce:@selector(randomAnimation) delay:x];


}
```

and fire up the sequence with

```
[_hero randomAnimation];
```

edit : if you dont want to expose the randomAnimation method, fire the animation when the object is added to the scene like this :

```
-(void) onEnter {
    [super onEnter];
    [self randomAnimation];
}
```