# How to schedule or call a method at random time interval in cocos2d iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to call a method at Irregular time interval means it should be random time plus i want it in some define range too.

Like : it should call at any second between 3 to 8 .

I tried this one :

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(myMethod:)  userInfo:nil repeats: YES];

void mymethod()
{
  if(arc4random() % 10 == 1)
  {
      // calling my method here;
  }
}
```

This way , i am not getting randomization which i want.

Any one can please help me on this !!!

Comment: how it is related to cocos2d exactly ? what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @giorashc have u heard of scheduling a method in cocos2d-iphone ?

Comment: @giorashc  if u have heard of it then have you ever schedule a method at random time of interval in cocos2d iphone ?

Comment: @shaqirsaiyed nothing in your code permits to identify this as a descendant of the CCNode class, thus giorashc's remark is perfectly valid. I am pretty certain he knows cocos's methods for scheduling. Try [self scheduleOnce:delay:] if this is a cocos's node.

Comment: @shaqirsaiyed I was just trying to understand what you were trying to do. NSTimer is not a cocos2d framework class so that why I was asking...

Comment: @giorashc ya you are absolutely right. NSTimer is not a cocos2d framework class, but part of The Foundation Kit. it's my mistake relating it to cocos2d framework

Comment: @YvesLeBorg ya it could be done using scheduleOnce scheduler too..thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can make a scheduler which will get called at random interval.

```
-(void)randomTimeScheduler{


int time = arc4random()%5;
int nextTimeOfCall = 3+time;

NSLog("it will be called after:%d",nextTimeOfCall);

[self performSelector:@selector(randomTimeScheduler) withObject:self afterDelay:nextTimeOfCall];

}
```

**You have to call it from your class and then it will work as a scheduler. And it has finite interval time 3-8.**